# Use query with addValueEventListener

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to fetch specific data from Firebase in my Android application. 
In the onCreate I define my DatabaseReference and the ArrayList:

```
databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("books");
books = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then to fill my ListView with the data:

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                
            books.clear();
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            String uid = user.getUid();
            //iterating through all the nodes
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Book bookrequest = postSnapshot.getValue(Book.class);
                books.add(bookrequest );
                }
            }
            BooksListing booksAdapter = new BooksListing(MainActivity.this, books);
            //attaching adapter to the listview
            listViewBooks.setAdapter(booksAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Now I only would like to get the books from Firebase which have my own UID.

```
type books {
  id: String;
  amount: Number;
  uid: uid;}
```

Where can I implement my query before transferring the data to my Android device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid();

databaseRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid)
    .addValueEventListener(new ... {
        ... onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // here will only contain books that have
                // uid equal to your user uid
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    });
```

Hope this helps